# Read object from array

Tags: symfony, twig

Using `print_r($session)`) I can see my session data like this:

```
(
    [code] => 123
    [profile] => 'Admin'
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Info] => 555
                )
        )
)
```

Ok, so if I want to print in screen via twig the `profile`, this works

```
{{ app.session.get('profile') }}
```

And I get `Admin` which is correct. **But how can I read the `Info` ?** I thought that something like

```
{{ app.session.get('data[0].Info') }}
```

would work but I'm getting blank data. If I use `{{ dump(data[0].Info) }}` shows the correct info (`555`).

Comment: try that {{ dump(data.0.Info) }}

Comment: Works too but I don't need to use dump, how can I use it with app.session.get() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it step-by-step. First pull the correct variable, afterwards treat it like an array:

```
{{ app.session.get('data')[0].Info }}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out later. Thanks